# Difference between DepthwiseConv2D and SeparableConv2D

Tags: keras

From the document, I know `SeparableConv2D` is a combination of depthwise and pointwise operation. However, when I call

```py
SeparableConv2D(100, 5, input_shape=(416,416,10) 

# total parameters is 1350

model.add(DepthwiseConv2D(5, input_shape=(416,416,10)))
model.add(Conv2D(100, 1))

# total parameters is 1360
```

Does it mean `SeparableConv2D` does not use bias in depthwise phase by default?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Correct, checking the source code (I did this for `tf.keras` but I suppose it is the same for standalone `keras`) shows that in `SeparableConv2D`, the separable convolution works using only filters, no biases, and a single bias vector is added at the end. The second version, on the other hand, has biases for both `DepthwiseConv2D` and `Conv2D`.

Given that convolution is a linear operation and you are using no non-linearity inbetween depthwise and 1x1 convolution, I would suppose that having two biases is unnecessary in this case, similar to how you don't use biases in a layer that is followed by batch normalization, for example. As such, the extra 10 parameters wouldn't actually improve the model (nor should they really hurt either).